# Can I run Linux software in Windows?

Tags: windows, emulation

In Linux we can run Windows software by using `wine`. I want the exact opposite, I want to run Linux software in Windows. Is it possible? If yes, how? **I don't want visualization or virtual box I want something only wine like.** 
simply in short, how to run `.deb` file into Windows.

Comment: This isn't really a question about Ubuntu: the nearest equivalent is probably [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/)

Comment: **W**ine **I**s **N**ot an **E**mulator

Comment: Wait until I get home, then I'll post an in depth answer...

Comment: @steeldriver yes! not fully Ubuntu related. semi Ubuntu related.

Comment: @blade19899 yes! I will wait.

Comment: I kinda posted a simple one instead. To hot to do anything in depth ;(

Comment: Could you please tell us _what_ you want to run in Windows?

Comment: @codingman not application specific. I run want anything or something.. general question ... like how to run debian soft into windows.

Comment: You question is not general it's [hypothetical](http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask). A lot of Free Software available in Ubuntu can run on other platforms than Linux, including Windows. You really need to be more specific here.

Comment: @LiveWireBT ok. & sorry. I remember `hypothetical` for next time.

Comment: @MadhavNikam hypothetically a VM e.g. VirtualBox or `cygwin` would work best. VM for full apps, `cygwin` for CLI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Linux terminal commands, there is [this](https://cygwin.com/).

For full apps, you can install Ubuntu under [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), and run it in seamless mode.

[andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/index.php) is a complete Ubuntu Linux system running seamlessly in Windows 2000 based systems (2000, XP, 2003, Vista, 7; 32-bit versions only). This project was started for Dynamism for the GP2X community, but its userbase far exceeds its original design. andLinux is free and will remain so, but donations are greatly needed.

---

[Cooperative Linux](http://www.colinux.org/) is the first working free and open source method for optimally running Linux on Microsoft Windows natively.

Comment: I want something like wine in windows. virtual box is not need or not want. something which is run like wine.

Comment: @MadhavNikam There is no Wine for Windows, the closest is Cygwin and you wouldn't even know that you are running it like for example in InfraRecorder. You don't seem to understand what Wine is and what it does, what the term ***Free Software*** defines and how the community around it works (providing ports for Windows in some cases), also you wouldn't know what to do with a full blown Cygwin installation and porting to Windows is safe to be considered off-topic here. Without an example your question is just hypothetical.

Answer (score 3):

## Portable Ubuntu Remix:

[Download site](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/portableubuntu/portableubuntu/DOS/Xming_for_Portable_Ubuntu_DOS.7z?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fportableubuntu%2F&ts=1435935445&use_mirror=ufpr)

This project consist in a portable image of Ubuntu that could run in Windows as a native win32 application. You could execute Linux applications and integrate it in your Windows desktop. This system can be bringing in any removable device such as pendrive.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is "you can't". To my knowledge there isn't a set of libraries that would allow an unmodified Ubuntu binary to run under Windows, similar to what WINE does.

The specific answer depending on what you want to run and how you want to run it would be:

1. You can run cywgin, which will give you many command-line utilities similar to what exists under Linux. Note that this is not really "running Linux software in Windows" since the applications are recompiled and Windows-native, plus they're not Linux-exclusive. They're usually distributed in the form of source code and you could compile them in any platform with the required toolset.
2. You can run Ubuntu in a virtual machine hosted under Windows (VirtualBox, VMWare). This isn't really "running Linux software in Windows" - You're running full, virtualized Linux and running Linux software on Linux/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a read , the following link hope it solves your problem
http://www.howtogeek.com/170870/5-ways-to-run-linux-software-on-windows/

Comment: Your answer qualifies as a link only answer, please include full instructions in your answer and note that the op didn't ask for virtualisation.